# Force buffers to always open with vertical split

Tags: buffers

When I open a new buffer I usually just do `:vsp something` which allows me to open a new buffer with a vertical split. However, when I don't control how the buffer should be opened (e.g. when typing `:help`) the new buffer is always opened with a horizontal split, which really annoys me. Is there anyway to change the default split direction?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Vim provides `:vert` to split vertically. 
There isn't any option to change the default horizontal split but you can add `:vert` before file to open it 
like `:vert help`

```
:vert[ical] {cmd}
    Execute {cmd}.  If it contains a command that splits a window,
    it will be split vertically.
```

Answer (score 6):

@Ashok's answer is good but if you do this often you may want to use `cabbrev` to do it for you.

Add this to your `.vimrc` to have vim automatically put in `:vert help` whenever you type `:help`

```
cabbrev help vert help
```

Comment: Only problem with this is that OP only gave help as an example. There are lots of other cases that could open a split that this won't catch. :/

Comment: @Tumbler41 it's not a perfect solution but that's why I wrote "if you do this often"

Comment: how can i position the buffer to the `last position` (far right), automatically?